# move to a new instance in an 2d array randomly once

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

so i a player on a 2d array, when i do an action i want the player to move to one of the 8 available blocks around him, the code below moves him randomly but does it twice

Map Before Moving

GrassGrassGrassGrass

Grass Rek  GrassGrass

GrassGrassGrassGrass

GrassGrassGrassGrass

Random Movement

0     0

0     0 //This shouldn't be happening

Map After Moving

GrassGrassGrassGrass

GrassGrassGrassGrass

GrassGrassGrassGrass

GrassGrassGrass Rek

```
import java.util.Random;

public class command_Movment implements command_Move {


inSwamp map = new inSwamp();
inSwamp rek = new Rek();
Random random = new Random();


int row = random.nextInt(3);
int col = random.nextInt(3);

@Override
public Command move() {

    for (int i = 0; i < map.grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.grid[i].length; j++) {

            if (map.grid[i][j] == rek.getName()) {

                try {
                    map.grid[i][j] = "Grass";
                    if (row == 0) {
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (row == 1) {
                        i--;
                    }

                    if (col == 0) {
                        j++;
                    }
                    if (col == 1) {
                        j--;
                    }

                    map.grid[i][j] = rek.getName();
                    System.out.println(col + "     " + row);

                    break;

                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                    if (row == 0) {
                        i--;
                    }
                    if (row == 1) {
                        i++;
                    }

                    if (col == 0) {
                        j--;
                    }
                    if (col == 1) {
                        j++;
                    }
                    map.grid[i][j] = rek.getName();
                    System.out.println("Error");

                    break;
                }



        }
    }


}

    return null;
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use == to compare strings, you should use equals method. so replace `if (map.grid[i][j] == rek.getName())` with `if (map.grid[i][j].equals(rek.getName()))`.

**Edit**: **PLEASE don't use label to break the modularity of the program!**
Please don't use catching ArrayIndexOutofBound exception to determine if an array index is correct or not. The exception should **NOT** happen. You should check the index first.

I updated my program for your random move: basically I thin you want to:
1) randomly move up or move down from the original position 2) if move up or move down exceeds the boundary of the matrix, don't move in that direction.

The following program should move rek to one of its 8 neighbors randomly without causing any ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

```
public Command move() {
    // randomly determine the moving direction
    // -1 means move left, 1 means move right
    int horizontal_direction = Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    // -1 means move up, 1 mean move down
    int vertical_direction = Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < map.grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.grid[i].length; j++) {

            if (map.grid[i][j].equals(rek.getName())) {
                map.grid[i][j] = "Grass"; // replace rek's current position with Grass\

                // if the newRow exceeds the boundaries, don't move in that direction
                int newRow = i + horizontal_direction;
                if (newRow < 0 || newRow == map.grid.length)
                    newRow = i;

                // if the newCol exceeds the boundaries, don't move in that direction
                int newCol = j + vertical_direction;
                if (newCol < 0 || newCol == map.grid[i].length)
                    newCol = j;

                map.grid[newRow][newCol] = rek.getName(); // move rek to the new position

                System.out.println(newRow + "     " + newCol);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changes them to .equals now and the code wasn't for anywhere in the grid, only the 8 available blocks around rek.

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderDelaney updated the code, this should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label like this to your outer loop:

```
outer:
for (int i = 0; i < map.grid.length; i++) {
    ......
}
```

And in the **try** block, break the loop this way:

```
map.grid[i][j] = rek.getName();
System.out.println(col + "     " + row);

break outer;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, never knew about that function before

Comment: You can solve this otherwise, you know. But this sort of 'hack' seems beneficial in such situation. Inspired from the assembly's GOTO and JUMP TO instructions.

Comment: @JDev I never knew this exists in Java. I voted down because I agree with your comment - this is very hacky and breaks the modularity of the program.